# Bootstrap Carousel with JQuery does not work on Android but works on iOS & WinOS 8

Tags: android, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am using **Bootstrap v3.3.2** with **JQuery 2.13** and **JQueryMobile 1.4.5**

The **bootstrap carousel** works smoothly on iPAD & Windows 8 Tablets but it **almost does not work** on **Android** tablets (**v4.4.2**)

On Android, the **swipe event does not fire easily**. You have to swipe (left or right) many times and then only one time it fires. So the swipe has issues on Android. While on other two platforms its like breeze.

Here is my code piece:

**HTML**

```
<div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">

        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="0" ></li>
            <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#Carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
        </ol>

        <div class="carousel-inner">

            <div class="item active">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <div>DATA 1</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <div>DATA 2</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <div>DATA 3</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
            </div>     

            <div class="item">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <div>DATA 4</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <div>DATA 5</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <div>DATA 6</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
            </div> 

            <div class="item">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <div>DATA 7</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <div>DATA 8</div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <div>DATA 9</div>
                        </div>
                    </div>  
            </div> 

        </div>
        <a data-slide="prev" href="#Carousel" class="left carousel-control leftArrowIcon"></a>
        <a data-slide="next" href="#Carousel" class="right carousel-control rightArrowIcon"></a>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$("#afterLoginPage").on("pageshow", function( event ) { 

        $('#Carousel').each(function(){             
             var $myCarousel = $(this);             
             $myCarousel.swipeleft(function() {
                 $(this).carousel('next');
                 console.log("Carousel - next"    );

             });             
             $myCarousel.swiperight(function() {
                 $(this).carousel('prev');
                 console.log("Carousel - prev"    );

             });
         }); 
});
```

Also tried in this way but no benefit:

```
$("#afterLoginPage").on("pageshow", function( event ) { 

        $("#Carousel").on("swiperight", function() { 
             console.log("Carousel - prev"    ); 
             $(this).parent().carousel('prev');
             // $(this).carousel('prev');   // did not work as well
         });  

         $("#Carousel").on("swipeleft", function() {  
            console.log("Carousel - next"    ); 
            $(this).parent().carousel('next');            
            // $(this).carousel('next');   // did not work as well
         });
});
```

Comment: there are issues wth JQM 1.4.4 and 1.4.5 with Android Webview and KitKat. -- https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/5534 -- You have a few Options. Drop to JQM version 1.4.3. Or Use touchswipe or Hammer Js to handle the swipes. Both are very easy to use and implement. http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/touchSwipe/demos/  -- http://hammerjs.github.io/ -- one of these 3 options should fix the swipe issues you have

Comment: Thanks for the help, I just used hammerjs and it worked well on all three platforms.

Comment: Would you mind to share your final solution please. I am intresting to do the same thing. Thank you in advance!